# Polars group_by_rolling only retains index and by columns

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate, python-polars

Using the same dataframe as in a previous question,

```
pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("Time", ['02/01/2018 07:05', '02/01/2018 07:07', '02/01/2018 07:08', '02/01/2018 07:09', '02/01/2018 07:10', '02/01/2018 07:12', '02/01/2018 07:13', '02/01/2018 07:14', '02/01/2018 07:18', '02/01/2018 07:26', '02/01/2018 07:38', '02/01/2018 07:39', '02/01/2018 07:45', '02/01/2018 07:48', '02/01/2018 07:49', '02/01/2018 07:50', '02/01/2018 07:52', '02/01/2018 07:53', '02/01/2018 07:56', '02/01/2018 07:57'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("Open", [8.05, 8.04, 8.02, 8.02, 8.02, 8.01, 8.01, 8.0, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.96, 7.96, 7.95, 7.94, 7.94, 7.93], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("High", [8.05, 8.04, 8.02, 8.02, 8.02, 8.01, 8.01, 8.0, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.96, 7.96, 7.95, 7.94, 7.94, 7.93], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("Low", [8.05, 8.01, 8.01, 8.02, 8.02, 8.01, 8.01, 8.0, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.94, 7.96, 7.94, 7.94, 7.94, 7.93], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("Close", [8.05, 8.01, 8.02, 8.02, 8.02, 8.01, 8.01, 8.0, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.94, 7.96, 7.94, 7.94, 7.94, 7.93], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("MA14", [8.13, 8.12, 8.11, 8.11, 8.1, 8.09, 8.08, 8.07, 8.06, 8.05, 8.04, 8.03, 8.02, 8.0, 8.0, 7.99, 7.99, 7.98, 7.98, 7.97], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("MA28", [8.1, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.09, 8.08, 8.08, 8.08, 8.07, 8.07, 8.06, 8.06, 8.05, 8.04, 8.04, 8.03], dtype=pl.Float64),
        pl.Series("PVT", [0.0, -0.3478, -0.2904, -0.2904, -0.2904, -0.3527, -0.3527, -0.3677, -0.374, -0.374, -0.404, -0.3376, -0.3376, -0.3489, -0.4792, -0.459, -0.6224, -0.6224, -0.6224, -0.6362], dtype=pl.Float64),
    ]
)
```

and using a previous answer to add a few more columns,

```
ohlc = jan_data.with_columns(
        DateTime = pl.col("Time").str.to_datetime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    ).with_columns(
        Date = pl.col("DateTime").dt.date().set_sorted(), 
        t = pl.col("DateTime").dt.time(),
        ones = pl.lit(1),
        vol = (2*(pl.col("High")-pl.col("Low"))/(pl.col("Open")+pl.col("Close"))).round(5),   
    ).with_columns(
        MA = pl.col("Close").rolling_mean(20).over("Date"),
        n = pl.col("ones").cumsum().over("Date")
    ).select(pl.exclude("ones"))
```

I want to try and create rolling forward lists using the `group_by_rolling` method:

```
def list_to_string(a):
    t = '['
    t = t + ','.join(str(x) for x in a)
    t = t + ']'

    return t

out = ohlc.group_by_rolling(
        index_column = 'n',
        period = '20i',
        offset = '0i',
        by = "Date",
    ).agg(
        pl.col("Close").map_elements(lambda col: list_to_string(col.to_list())).alias("lists"),
    )
```

The problem is that `print(out.head(10))` is,

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌────────────┬─────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ n   ┆ lists                             │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---                               │
│ date       ┆ i32 ┆ str                               │
╞════════════╪═════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 1   ┆ [8.01,8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 2   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 3   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.99,7.… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 4   ┆ [8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.99,7.99,7.… │
│ …          ┆ …   ┆ …                                 │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 7   ┆ [8.0,7.99,7.99,7.98,7.99,7.99,7.… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 8   ┆ [7.99,7.99,7.98,7.99,7.99,7.98,7… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 9   ┆ [7.99,7.98,7.99,7.99,7.98,7.94,7… │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 10  ┆ [7.98,7.99,7.99,7.98,7.94,7.96,7… │
└────────────┴─────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

so most of the original columns have been removed. Is there a way to retain them? Ideally the output should be something like,

```
shape: (20, 15)
┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ Time             ┆ Open ┆ High ┆ Low  ┆ … ┆ vol     ┆ MA     ┆ n   ┆ lists                       │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---                         │
│ str              ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆   ┆ f64     ┆ f64    ┆ i64 ┆ str                         │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════╡
│ 02/01/2018 07:05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null   ┆ 1   ┆ [8.01,8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ .01,8…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:07 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.01 ┆ … ┆ 0.00374 ┆ null   ┆ 2   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ .0,7.…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:08 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.01 ┆ … ┆ 0.00125 ┆ null   ┆ 3   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7. │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ 99,7.…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:09 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null   ┆ 4   ┆ [8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.99,7. │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ 99,7.…                      │
│ …                ┆ …    ┆ …    ┆ …    ┆ … ┆ …       ┆ …      ┆ …   ┆ …                           │
│ 02/01/2018 07:52 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.00126 ┆ null   ┆ 17  ┆ [7.94,7.94,7.93,7.93,7.9,7. │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ 88,7.…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:53 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null   ┆ 18  ┆ [7.94,7.93,7.93,7.9,7.88,7. │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ 89,7.…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:56 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null   ┆ 19  ┆ [7.93,7.93,7.9,7.88,7.89,7. │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ 9,7.9…                      │
│ 02/01/2018 07:57 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ 7.93 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ 7.9855 ┆ 20  ┆ [7.93,7.9,7.88,7.89,7.9,7.9 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆        ┆     ┆ ,7.92…                      │
└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of any `group_by`/`agg` is going to be the columns you told it that you care about and no more.

It's not clear in what form you want to retain the original columns as they're grouped but here's the most generic way where each one will have a list of all the original values for its group.

```
ohlc.group_by_rolling(
        index_column = 'n',
        period = '20i',
        offset = '0i',
        by = "Date",
    ).agg(
        pl.col("Close").map_elements(lambda col: list_to_string(col.to_list())).alias("lists"),
        pl.exclude('n','Date')
    )
shape: (20, 15)
┌────────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ Date       ┆ n   ┆ lists      ┆ Time       ┆ … ┆ DateTime   ┆ t          ┆ vol       ┆ MA        │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ date       ┆ i32 ┆ str        ┆ list[str]  ┆   ┆ list[datet ┆ list[time] ┆ list[f64] ┆ list[f64] │
│            ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆ ime[μs]]   ┆            ┆           ┆           │
╞════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 1   ┆ [8.01,8.02 ┆ ["02/01/20 ┆ … ┆ [2018-01-0 ┆ [07:07:00, ┆ [0.00374, ┆ [null,    │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.02,8.02 ┆ 18 07:07", ┆   ┆ 2          ┆ 07:08:00,  ┆ 0.00125,  ┆ null, …   │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.01,8.01 ┆ "02/01/201 ┆   ┆ 07:07:00,  ┆ …          ┆ … 0.0]    ┆ 7.9855]   │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8…        ┆ 8…         ┆   ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:57:00]  ┆           ┆           │
│            ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆ …          ┆            ┆           ┆           │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 2   ┆ [8.02,8.02 ┆ ["02/01/20 ┆ … ┆ [2018-01-0 ┆ [07:08:00, ┆ [0.00125, ┆ [null,    │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.02,8.01 ┆ 18 07:08", ┆   ┆ 2          ┆ 07:09:00,  ┆ 0.0, …    ┆ null, …   │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.01,8.0, ┆ "02/01/201 ┆   ┆ 07:08:00,  ┆ …          ┆ 0.0]      ┆ 7.9855]   │
│            ┆     ┆ 7.…        ┆ 8…         ┆   ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:57:00]  ┆           ┆           │
│            ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆ …          ┆            ┆           ┆           │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 3   ┆ [8.02,8.02 ┆ ["02/01/20 ┆ … ┆ [2018-01-0 ┆ [07:09:00, ┆ [0.0,     ┆ [null,    │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.01,8.01 ┆ 18 07:09", ┆   ┆ 2          ┆ 07:10:00,  ┆ 0.0, …    ┆ null, …   │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.0,7.99, ┆ "02/01/201 ┆   ┆ 07:09:00,  ┆ …          ┆ 0.0]      ┆ 7.9855]   │
│            ┆     ┆ 7.…        ┆ 8…         ┆   ┆ 2018-01-02 ┆ 07:57:00]  ┆           ┆           │
│            ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆ …          ┆            ┆           ┆           │
│ 2018-01-02 ┆ 4   ┆ [8.02,8.01 ┆ ["02/01/20 ┆ … ┆ [2018-01-0 ┆ [07:10:00, ┆ [0.0,     ┆ [null,    │
│            ┆     ┆ ,8.01,8.0, ┆ 18 07:10", ┆   ┆ 2          ┆ 07:12:00,  ┆ 0.0, …    ┆ null, …   │
│            ┆     ┆ 7.99,7.99, ┆ "02/01/201 ┆   ┆ 07:10:00,  ┆ …          ┆ 0.0]      ┆ 7.9855]   │
...
│            ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆ 07:57:00]  ┆            ┆           ┆           │
│ -109782-01 ┆ 20  ┆ []         ┆ []         ┆ … ┆ []         ┆ []         ┆ []        ┆ []        │
│ -05        ┆     ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆            ┆            ┆           ┆           │
└────────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

where `pl.exclude` means all the columns except whatever you put there. It's a shortcut for `pl.all().exclude()` which makes more intuitive sense but it more typing. Since you're already asking for 'n' and 'Date' as part of the `group_by` you don't want to ask for them again with `pl.all()`.

Based on the edit, you should do a self-join to restore the columns. Also, the UDF can be replicated with expressions so that's in here too.

```
ohlc.join(ohlc.group_by_rolling(
        index_column = 'n',
        period = '20i',
        offset = '0i',
        by = "Date",
    ).agg(
        pl.col("Close").cast(pl.Utf8()).str.concat(',').alias('lists')
    ).with_columns(
        (pl.lit("[") + pl.col('lists') + pl.lit("]")).alias('lists')
    ), on=['Date','n']
)
shape: (19, 15)
┌──────────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ Time             ┆ Open ┆ High ┆ Low  ┆ … ┆ vol     ┆ MA   ┆ n   ┆ lists                         │
│ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆   ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---                           │
│ str              ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆   ┆ f64     ┆ f64  ┆ i32 ┆ str                           │
╞══════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪═══╪═════════╪══════╪═════╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 02/01/2018 07:05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ 8.05 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null ┆ 1   ┆ [8.01,8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8.0 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆      ┆     ┆ 1,8…                          │
│ 02/01/2018 07:07 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.04 ┆ 8.01 ┆ … ┆ 0.00374 ┆ null ┆ 2   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆      ┆     ┆ ,7.…                          │
│ 02/01/2018 07:08 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.01 ┆ … ┆ 0.00125 ┆ null ┆ 3   ┆ [8.02,8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.99 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆      ┆     ┆ ,7.…                          │
│ 02/01/2018 07:09 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ 8.02 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ [8.02,8.01,8.01,8.0,7.99,7.99 │
│                  ┆      ┆      ┆      ┆   ┆         ┆      ┆     ┆ ,7.…                          │
│ …                ┆ …    ┆ …    ┆ …    ┆ … ┆ …       ┆ …    ┆ …   ┆ …                             │
│ 02/01/2018 07:50 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ 7.96 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null ┆ 16  ┆ [7.94,7.94,7.94,7.93]         │
│ 02/01/2018 07:52 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.95 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.00126 ┆ null ┆ 17  ┆ [7.94,7.94,7.93]              │
│ 02/01/2018 07:53 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null ┆ 18  ┆ [7.94,7.93]                   │
│ 02/01/2018 07:56 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ 7.94 ┆ … ┆ 0.0     ┆ null ┆ 19  ┆ [7.93]                        │
└──────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Ideally the form should be the original dataframe `ohlc` and the new column `lists`. I definitely do not want to create more lists that contain elements from the other columns.

Comment: The original has more rows than the group_by_rolling result so you have to choose an aggregation (ie mean, median, max, min, etc) if you only want a single value per row.

Comment: If you can give an example of what you want the output to look like then I can help you out.

Comment: Thats strange. When I use `write_csv` (the original data is 6645 rows) both the original and the `group_by` dataframe have the same number of rows.

Comment: I have included an example of the required output in the original question

Comment: the way you replaced the UDF is ingenious.

Comment: is there a reason why the  `(pl.lit("[") + pl.col('lists') + pl.lit("]")).alias('lists')` cannot be combined with `pl.col("Close").cast(pl.Utf8()).str.concat(',').alias('lists')` so we don't have to use `with_columns`

Comment: The simplest reason is that it doesn't work, I tried. I think it's because the `str.concat` has to fully resolve before you put the brackets around it otherwise the shapes and/or data types aren't compatible.